# Read CSV file as Array with AppleScript

Tags: excel, macos, csv, applescript

I would like to read in a CSV file in as a 2D array and then return it back to a CSV file. 
Let's say that this is my CSV file. It is an excel file and the | implies the adjacent cell:

```
family | type
Doctor | Pediatrics
Engineer | Chemical
```

From what I understand, there are no arrays on applescript, just lists and records. If it would be better to do this with a XLSX file, please let me know.

Answer (score 7):

Nigel's CSV-to-list converter is the best I have seen ...

http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=125444#p125444

For your example, use these settings:

```
set csvText to "family | type
Doctor | Pediatrics
Engineer | Chemical"
csvToList(csvText, {separator:"|"}, {trimming:true})
```

v2

```
set csvText to read "/Users/user1385816/Desktop/yourfile.csv"
csvToList(csvText, {}, {trimming:true})
```

Comment: It is the best I've seen myself too. But all solutions in AppleScript seems a bit slow with a lot of data (30K lines or more). Then you have to find performance somewhere else. I'm using a self written command line utility written in C that reads in an CSV file and write out a AS 2 dimensional list. Then do a 'run script' to coerce the string into an list.

Comment: Nice. Although I am sure it is no where as fast, I incorporated Nigel's script into one that imports everything into a sqlite3 database. After I am done with the data, I export it back to csv.

Comment: Cool. I was just wondering, on this specific handler, the parameter csvText confuses me. Can I just set my csv file to be csvText?

Comment: Also what is getting returned? I'm sorry, I am rather new to Applescript. It seems as if it is a record being returned?

Comment: You know what I just realized. I think I was stupid and I showed my example incorrectly. The | was meant to signify a new cell in the CSV file.

Comment: Sweet. It works great! So this is returning a record correct? And I can manipulate it the same way one would manipulate an array on Java?

Comment: It returns a list of lists, just as the solution regulus6633 offered does.

Answer (score 4):

An array is just a list in applescript, so you want a 2d array or a list-of-lists in applescript-speak. If you understand applescript's text item delimiters then your task is just simple manipulation to convert strings into lists and vice versa. So I wrote you a couple handlers to make the task easy for you; textToTwoDArray() and twoDArrayToText(). This first example shows how to convert your string into a list-of-lists using textToTwoDArray().

NOTE: you have to be careful of the line endings in a text file because they can be either a carriage return (character id 13) or a line feed (character id 10). You can see I used character id 10 in my code but if you aren't getting the proper results try "13".

```
set fileText to "family | type
Doctor | Pediatrics
Engineer | Chemical"

textToTwoDArray(fileText, character id 10, " | ")

on textToTwoDArray(theText, mainDelimiter, secondaryDelimiter)
    set {tids, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, mainDelimiter}
    set firstArray to text items of theText
    set text item delimiters to secondaryDelimiter
    set twoDArray to {}
    repeat with anItem in firstArray
        set end of twoDArray to text items of anItem
    end repeat
    set text item delimiters to tids
    return twoDArray
end textToTwoDArray
```

And here's how to convert a list-of-lists back into your string using twoDArrayToText().

```
set twoDArray to {{"family", "type"}, {"Doctor", "Pediatrics"}, {"Engineer", "Chemical"}}

twoDArrayToText(twoDArray, character id 10, " | ")

on twoDArrayToText(theArray, mainDelimiter, secondaryDelimiter)
    set {tids, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, secondaryDelimiter}
    set t to ""
    repeat with anItem in theArray
        set t to t & (anItem as text) & mainDelimiter
    end repeat
    set text item delimiters to tids
    return (text 1 thru -2 of t)
end twoDArrayToText
```

So now all you have to do is figure out how to read and write to a text file with applescript. Good luck ;)

Comment: Thank you! I would 1 up you but I lack the reputation to do so. But know that you have been very useful

Answer (score 0):

If your question is just about modeling your CSV data in AppleScript, the solution is to use a list of records like this:

```
set csvData to {{family:"Doctor", type:"Engineer"}, {family:"Engineer", type:"Chemical"}}
```

you can then read that out again inside a `repeat with aRow in csvData` loop.

A technical note: AppleScript lists are implemented as vectors, meaning they are ordered and can be accessed by numerical index (beginning at index 1) – they behave much like an array in most other languages.